# chinese text to speech Translation in offline mode in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, text-to-speech

I need Chinese text to speech translation library in offline mode for iPhone app. There are libraries available for online (Chinese Text To Speech Conversion) like [ispeech](http://www.ispeech.org/text.to.speech)  but I need any free library that works in offline mode.

So how can I convert Chinese text into speech in offline mode?

Any help is appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer [OpenEars](http://www.politepix.com/openears/). It's an offline mode iOS framework for iPhone voice recognition and speech synthesis (TTS) .

To support  Chinese language, just change its default english **acoustic model and grammar files(.languagemodel & .dic)** with **Chinese acoustic model and grammar files**.

Regarding different language,Please note below comments

> Speech recognition engines require two types of files to recognize
>   speech. They require an **acoustic model**, which is created by taking
>   audio recordings of speech and their transcriptions (taken from a
>   speech corpus), and 'compiling' them into a statistical
>   representations of the sounds that make up each word (through a
>   process called 'training'). They also require a **language model** or
>   **grammar file**. A language model is a file containing the probabilities
>   of sequences of words. A grammar is a much smaller file containing
>   sets of predefined combinations of words. Language models are used for
>   dictation applications, whereas grammars are used in desktop command
>   and control or telephony interactive voice response (IVR) type
>   applications.

So search for a **Chinese acoustic model and grammar files** and download it, replace these with Openears(or any other speech engine's) default  acoustic model and grammar files. That's it.

Downloaded Acoustic model should have the following files

```
mdef
feat.params
mixture_weights
means
noisedict
transition_matrices
variances
```

So find these Openears files and replace with downloaded Chinese acoustic model. Don't forget to change the grammar files.

or **Create your own acoustic model** using [**CMUSphinx tutorial**](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam).

You can download different acoustic models from  [cmusphinx website](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/).

For chinese,please do a google search and get it.

Comment: +1 for this detailed explanation. I will check and get back to you.